# How to demultiplex MinION fastQ files without Porechop?

Tags: r, minion

I recently got fastQ files from a MinION sequencer. I would like to demultiplex these files.

Is there any other software to demultiplex (no porechop) in or outside Artic protocol? I would like to learn options different from porechop.

Thank you!

Comment: A quick google finds https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/demultiplex-nanopore-reads-with-custom-barcodes, https://www.protocols.io/view/demultiplexing-nanopore-reads-with-last-xj3fkqn, https://github.com/nanoporetech/qcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Guppy basecaller itself now has the ability to internally perform multiplexing. That is currently the preferred option.

If for some reason, you still want a stand-alone application to demultiplex already basecalled reads, then `qcat` is an option: https://github.com/nanoporetech/qcat

Answer (score 1):

I have written up my own semi-manual method for demultiplexing Nanopore reads. As distinct from the other methods that are commonly used, it searches the *entire* read for potential barcode sequences, and splits out identified chimeric reads (containing multiple barcode sequences) into a separate file:

https://dx.doi.org/10.17504/protocols.io.7vmhn46